# Font-size is too small on smaller resolutions

Tags: css, responsive-design

Here is my code:

```
<p> font-size: 2vh; </p>
```

Text is nicely visible on high resolutions:

[image: Image 1]

But on smaller resolutions:

[image: Image 2]

How I can make text, that is not too small on smaller resolutions and not too big on high resolutions?
If I have to use media-queries, then what's the point of vh/vw units?

My viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Small code:

```
<head>  
<meta charset="UTF-8">  
<title>title</title>    
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="files/css/style.css"> 
</head>

<body>
<div id="logo">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus vel mattis risus.
Maecenas vel mauris ex. Curabitur mollis nibh sit amet egestas
fermentum. Ut posuere id sapien in suscipit. Integer a ultrices
metus, nec faucibus ipsum. Morbi nec venenatis nunc. In dignissim
dignissim velit ac finibus.</p>
</div>
</body>
```

css file:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #31302f;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px; /* for internet explorer */
    font-size: 2vh;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#logo p {
    font-size: 20px; /* for internet explorer */
    font-size: 2vh;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Can you add a small code snippet?

Comment: Yes, i edited just now

Comment: Modified the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`vh` units for font sizes are not ideal, since they are actually a percentage of the screen/device height. On a 480px high device 2vh means 9.6 pixels, which is definitely too small for regular text. IMO it's better to use the `em` or  `rem` units.

`rem` relates to the basic ("root") font-size of the browser (which in a mobile browser usually is set in a way that fits the device), `em` is in relation to the font-size of the parent element - inherited, which can be a bit trickier. In both cases one `rem/em` means 100% of the referenced size (see above), so for example `1.6 rem` is 160% of the root size, which can be a good value for a header.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the meta tag for mobile resolutions. Hence the resolution will be corrected for mobile screens.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

You can find the details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).

From your code there is no issue in your code. You will need to add [media query](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to adjust the font size.

I have added a sample code.

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
            #logo {
                font-size: 25px;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="logo">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus vel mattis risus. Maecenas vel mauris ex. Curabitur mollis nibh sit amet egestas fermentum. Ut posuere id sapien in suscipit. Integer a ultrices metus, nec faucibus ipsum. Morbi nec venenatis nunc. In dignissim dignissim velit ac finibus.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I will use rem units and media queries. You helped me too.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have in the header:

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Yes, exactly the same